# How to set navigation params from outside navigation stack?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a header in my app that needs to render a different button depending on whether or not the user has notifications. This is how I currently have it set up in my pages:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'My Profile',
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          type="clear"
          icon={() => <Icon
            type="material-community"
            size={25}
            name={UserProvider.bNotifications ? 'bell' : 'bell-outline'}
            color={UserProvider.bNotifications ? COLORS.WARNING : COLORS.WHITE}
          />}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications', null)}
        />
      )
    }
  };
```

The problem is, if `UserProvider.bNotifications` changes value, the header button doesn't update unless the page is changed / rerendered.

I want to switch to use the `navigation` property that is passed into those `navigationOptions`, but I don't no how to access it from outside the navigation stack. `UserProvider` is a static class (NOT a component) so I can't access the navigation prop through the usual manner (or by using the `useNavigation` hook).

I do have a `NavigationProvider` class that has access to the `NavigationContainer` for the app. I use it to trigger navigation without components. Is there some way I can set the params on the navigation property using that same reference?

NavigationProvider:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function getNavigator() {
  return _navigator;
}

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

function goBack() {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.back()
  );
}

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
  getNavigator,
  goBack
};
```

The ref is set like this in my top level App component:

```
<AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          console.log(navigatorRef.props.navigation);
          NavigationProvider.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
```

**EDIT - UserProvider**
This is just the gist of my UserProvider class, but should convey how it works.

```
export default class UserProvider {
  private static _bNotifications: boolean;

  static get bNotifications(): boolean {
    if (!this.hasInitNotifications)
      this.initNotficationWatch();
    return this._bNotifications;
  }

  static set bNotifications(bNotifications: boolean) {
    this._bNotifications = bNotifications;
  }

  static initNotficationWatch() {
    //Firebase listener on notification
    if(notifications){
      this.bNotifications = true;
    } else {
      this.bNotifications = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In previous projects with a similar need, I've had each page subscribe to an Observable to keep track of notifications. While still completely possible in this instance, having each separate page handle it's own subscription is a bit tedious. It would be much cleaner to be able to set the navigation params.

Answer (score 0):

**How to set navigation params from outside navigation stack?**

to do this you have to utilize the `getParam` method that comes from the `navigation` prop. the way I would di it would be to set a variable to a parameter that would equal to `UserProvider.bNotifications`.

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
 let notifications = navigation.getParam('notifications')
    return {
      title: 'My Profile',
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          type="clear"
          icon={() => <Icon
            type="material-community"
            size={25}
            name={notifications ? 'bell' : 'bell-outline'}
            color={notifications ? COLORS.WARNING : COLORS.WHITE}
          />}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications', null)}
        />
      )
    }
  };
```

> you can set the param to an initial value by adding it as a second argument if needed `navigation.getParam('paramName', 'param initial value')`

**To update the parameter** you need to use the `setParams` method. For this you can use the **useNavigation** hook.

> You can also do this inside of a functions instead of a element

```js
// remember to const navigation = useNavigation()

 <Button
    title="Update param"
    onPress={() => navigation.setParams({notifications: 'new value'})}
  />
```

> you can also initiate the value this way... but I would recommend to initialize the value inside your `navigationOptions`

**I haven't tested the code but it should work**

**RN DOCS**: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/headers/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as stated in the question: "`UserProvider` is a static class (NOT a component) so I can't access the navigation prop through the usual manner (or by using the `useNavigation` hook)."

Which is the root of the issue. How do I access the navigation prop without being inside a component?

Comment: @Tristan can you share your UserProvider?

Comment: Edited the question to include a demonstration for how my UserProvider class is set up.